# Unity starter code is telling me that method must have a return type

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class playerController : MonoBehaviour { // <-- this is where the error is
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }
}
```

Unity is telling me that "Method must have a return type [Assembly-CSharp]", but I haven't even written anything yet.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Unity documentation (https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Start.html), `MonoBehaviour.Start()` has a return type of `IEnumerator` (not `void`). Therefore your code should liok as follows:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class playerController : MonoBehaviour {
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    IEnumerator Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Nevermind, thanks but it runs fine even with all the "errors". I think Visual Studio Code is just being weird.